# Does dependency injection (in NestJS, for example) depends on TypeScript features?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

When applying the dependency injection pattern in NestJS, like in [this example from the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#dependency-injection):

```js
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateCatDto } from './dto/create-cat.dto';
import { CatsService } from './cats.service';
import { Cat } from './interfaces/cat.interface';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private catsService: CatsService) {}

  // Some other methods...
}
```

How does this work? As far as I understand, TypeScript will be compiled to plain JavaScript, and then the class type (`CatsService`) will disappear. How does NestJS know what class to inject in this case?

Comment: You can have DI in nodejs too, take a look:
https://medium.com/@magnusjt/dependency-injection-in-nodejs-9601a19c1f36

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection *in general* does not depend on typescript, and even in NestJS it can be done in (mostly) plain JavaScript by using Babel as a transpiler. [I've gone into a bit of detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779031/nestjs-dependency-inyection-and-provider-registration/65779434#65779434) about how the decorators work with typescript, and Semyon Volkov has shown how the decorators transpile as well. So inherently, no, it doesn't depend on Typescript, the way Nest *wants* you to do it (being opinionated and all) does.

In your example, Nest will read the type of `design:paramtypes` and see that there is a `CatsService` class, so it knows to match up the class names and inject a `CatsService` here. There's a lot more going on under the hood, when it comes to keeping track of what modules have access to what, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection does not depend on the typescript. Whenever we boot up the nest app, a Dependency Injection (DI) container gets created for us. DI is just an object.

Nest will look at the all different classes that we created except controllers. It will register all those different classes with the DI container. The container will check all the dependencies that are required for each class and map this class to its dependencies:

```
   class1 ---> dependencies
   class2 ---> dependencies
   class3 ---> it might now have any dependency
```

Then eventually we want to create the controller. we tell DI to create the controller with the required dependencies. DI will look at the constructor argument and see all the dependencies that are required. the container will see that it needs to create a service and service needs to create some dependencies.

So DI container will create the instances of required dependencies and store each instance internally so if in the future another class needs to those instances it can use them. Now dependencies are already created and DI container will use those to create the Controller and return it.

As you see we do not worry about creating all those services ourselves. DI container will take care of it for us.

Dependency injection is used for reusing the code and test the app easier.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example. This:

```
@Injectable()
export default class RequestService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(RequestEntity)
    private requestEntityRepository: Repository<RequestEntity>,
  ) {}
```

Is being transpiled to this:

```
let RequestService = class RequestService {
    constructor(requestEntityRepository) {
        this.requestEntityRepository = requestEntityRepository;
    }
...

RequestService = __decorate([
    common_1.Injectable(),
    __param(0, typeorm_1.InjectRepository(RequestEntity_1.default)),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [typeorm_2.Repository])
], RequestService);
exports.default = RequestService;
```